# Finding Memory Leak in Go Application

Tags: opencv, go, memory-leaks

I've got a simple program that reads frames off a webcam and puts pointers to them on a channel in a goroutine. Another portion reads the frame pointers from the channel and pops them onto another queue. This other queue then does some additional processing to them, and when this additional processing is done, a bunch of memory gets allocated that apparently never gets garbage collected. I'm in over my head trying to figure out why:

This function reads the frames off the channel in a loop:

```
func (mr *OpenCVMotionRunner) Run() error {
log.Println("Starting motion detection... ")

// inMotion := false
win := opencv.NewWindow("GoOpenCV: VideoPlayer")
defer win.Destroy()

test := mr.md.(*CV2FrameDiffMotionDetector)
for {
    f := mr.imageChan.PopFrame()
    mr.frame = nil
    switch f := f.(type) {
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Unknown frame type")
    case *BSFrame:
        mr.frame = f.ToOpenCVFrame()
    case *OpenCVFrame:
        mr.frame = f
    }
    f = nil
    test.SetCurrent(mr.frame)
    delta := test.Delta()
    // win.ShowImage(mr.frame.image)
    if delta != nil {
        win.ShowImage(delta)
        opencv.WaitKey(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("wtf")
    }
}

return nil
```

}

It appears that the problematic part is this specifically:

```
mr.frame = f.ToOpenCVFrame()
```

This is the type and the method:

```
// Frame with byte slice image
type BSFrame struct {
    image  []byte
    Time   time.Time
    Width  uint32
    Height uint32
}

func (f *BSFrame) ToOpenCVFrame() *OpenCVFrame {
    img := opencv.DecodeImageMem(f.image)
    return &OpenCVFrame{
        image:  img,
        Time:   f.Time,
        Width:  f.Width,
        Height: f.Height,
    }
}
```

This is the destination type:

```
type OpenCVFrame struct {
    image  *opencv.IplImage
    Time   time.Time
    Width  uint32
    Height uint32
}
```

PopFrame, FYI, is just a method on an type that aliases a channel:

```
type BSFrameChan chan *BSFrame

func (fc BSFrameChan) PopFrame() (frame Frame) {
    frame = <-fc
    return
}
```

Hopefully this is enough code for the problem to present itself. The rest is [here](https://github.com/jaymell/gosmartcam) if needed.

Comment: You can't really leak memory in Go, and I don't see any goroutines being called that could be left running, so the memory most likely is being used by OpenCV. Does the Go runtime show the memory being allocated? Are you ever releasing the memory used by OpenCV?

Comment: As JimB said, memory probably isn't released. Check out https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo, perhaps the C.free(unsafe.Pointer(..)) can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at trying to free the C resources directly. I'll post an update when I get it working.

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily free pointers to try and close the leak, you need to follow the API for the library you're using. OpenCV has documented functions to free specific data structures which the user is expected to call.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. The library I'm using for the go bindings indeed has a Release method for images. Using it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [go library I'm using for the OpenCV bindings](https://github.com/lazywei/go-opencv) provides a `Release` method on images to deallocate memory when done with an image. This fixes the problem.